# Line Break in index of ArrayList

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**I am reading a text line with FileInputStream at one of its index in ArrayList which contains a Line Break and using it to display in TextView. But problem is that \n is being displayed instead of making a line break.
I also checked Whether an Arraylist can contain "\n" and it worked exactly how I wanted
but only when am declaring it within my class like -data.add(1,"xyz\nxyz"). but the same is not working when I read line from text file.**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static ArrayList<String> data;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    data=new ArrayList<>();
    tv1=findViewById(R.id.text1);
    tv2=findViewById(R.id.text2);
```

Reading text file

```
 File fi = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Path /test.txt");

    if (fi.exists()){

        try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fi.getPath());
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();


            while (line != null) {
                data.add(0,line);
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

Displaying elements of ArrayList in TextView

```
    tv1.setText(data.get(0));                         // TextView display "\n" instead of line break.                   
    data.add(1,"\n\nhello here is a\nline break");    // This works fine as expected, text is displayed in new line
    tv2.setText(data.get(1));
```

Comment: data.add(0,line); ??? Why not  data.add(line); ?

Comment: `line = bufferedReader.readLine();` Variable `line` will not contain line breaks so we cannot follow your problem description. Better tell where those line breaks would come from.

Comment: I did it both works fine, has same output. Just to show that am storing line at index (0) of arraylist, I did it

Comment: Ok, but whatever variable line  will read contain I am passing that string to arraylist. Further arraylist can  decode here's line break in that string. so what's the issue.

Comment: You did not manage to tell your issue in such a way that i could follow you.

Comment: I have edited my code , so you can see how I have declared my arraylist

Comment: Are you suggesting that somewhere in your textfile you have a line like "abc\nxyz" ? well of course you will thent see  "abc\nxyz" when you try to display that line. No need to use an intermediate array lis. Put that line directly in a text view. In your text file "the \n in "abc\nxyz" is not a -single- newline character but two separate characters.

Comment: Well you are reading all lines from your text file if you use .readLine(). readLine() stops at every newline character. But as said before: `the \n in "abc\nxyz" is not a -single- newline character but two separate characters.` You can recognise the invisible new line characters in a text file when the text starts at a new line. The value of a newline charactyer is 10.

Comment: Exactly, you are right but the reason why am using an intermediate here because an arraylist can understand \n as one line break. Even I have already ensured that. Because when I use data.add(1, "xyz\nxyz"),  then the element 1 of data array is displayed in two different lines.

Comment: Indeed. But that is coding. If you use a string like "xyz\nxyz" in your code then the compiler converts the \n to 10 to make it a newline character. (You cannot enter a <return> or <enter> otherwise in a string. But in a textfile  "xyz\nxyz" the \n is just text and no newline character. Wrong thoughts sorry. Wrong preassumption.

Comment: Try `data.add (  "xyz\\nxyz" );` to see how you add such a text while coding to see \n.

Comment: ok but anything written inside double quote is a String then what makes a difference a string from a text file and one directly passed in arraylist  as parameter, Both has different  results. but both were strings for arraylist. Then why these two String cases is being treated differently.

Comment: That i just told you. And... again... all has nothing to do with that array list. Just use the text view directly.

Comment: Actually that arraylist has many elements and each of these elements has to be displayed in different pages. And so why am using each element to contain different lines. And then displaying each one of these one by one. And because my its each element represents one complete page hence it has few line breaks which is not being displayed.

Comment: I tried "\\n" even that is not working

Comment: Sigh.. Sadly you missed the point of the difference between newline characters in text files and in code strings. Well i did my best..

Comment: well thank u. I got u that both the cases has different meaning but if  there's way to overcome this issue. I'll be thankful.

Comment: @ErenYeager, blackapps is right. Don't put a "\n" in a text file and expect it to be read by java as a new line. When you are writing a string in a code the java compiler replaces "\n" for you (as blackapps already told you) but when you read a file the compiler is not involved and no one will interpret those "\n" for you. Instead, when creating the file just hit the "Enter" keyword to generate a new line and it will work as such.

Comment: line = bufferedReader.readLine(); line = line.replace("\\n", "\n");

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much this statement solved my issue and it's working as fine as I wanted.